# How to read request body from HttpServletRequest in Spring Boot and redirecting same request to another endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

The request is coming to an API Gateway where i want to extract request body and store in DB.
Then the request is routed to another service where it will be executed.

Currently when i use **request.getInputStream()** , this data will not be able for the other service.

> HttpServletRequest is an interface which exposes getInputStream()  method to read the body. By default, the data from this InputStream can be **read only once**.

Referred to [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times#:~:text=Spring's%20ContentCachingRequestWrapper,-Spring%20provides%20a&text=This%20class%20provides%20a%20method,body%20by%20consuming%20the%20InputStream.](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but again,we are still using        request.getInputStream() in the Gateway service so it is not available later.

Can someone please help out with this

Comment: Maybe Apache Commons Tee-streams would make some help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/commons_io/commons_io_teeinputstream.htm https://www.tutorialspoint.com/commons_io/commons_io_teeoutputstream.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create new request by using restTemplate class in springboot which present in Spring Web packages.

you can do it like below:

```
HttpEntity<String> newrequest = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        "http://localhost:8080/myother-endpoint",
        HttpMethod.POST,
        newrequest,
        String.class
    );
```

Before using restTemplate first configure the bean:

```
 @Configuration
public class MyTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

and inject it into your controller class using @Autowired annotation.